# Simple Python environment for learning the language on Android tablet?

Tags: android, python, tablet

Is there a simple environment like idle for someone to learn their first programming language - Python, on an Android tablet?

I am not after the complexity of creating apps. They just need to learn basic Python.

Thanks.

Comment: you may want to check out http://www.learnpython.org/ ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ithink I'llgo for @levon 's sugestion of the web-based learnpython.org. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since installing an IDE like how you would do on your desktop/laptop is out of the question, your options would boil down to:

1. App: Personally I haven't seen an app out there yet which has such capabilities.
2. Web: Here you will find options. Web based IDEs have been around for a while now. Two websites which I can think of where you could learn programming with one of those IDEs would be

   - [codeacademy.com](http://codeacademy.com)
   - [programr.com](http://programr.com)

- Relfor